# Error while creating python Module in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have installed PyDev in My eclipse. And also i have configured Interpreter-Python to Python26 which has already installed in my windows OS. I am able to create the python project.But when I am creating Python Module in eclipse Error Log I got some Exception as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.isBusy()Z from class org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider
    at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.runUpdates(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:1050)
    at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.processRunnables(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:1015)
    at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.processDelta(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:994)
    at org.python.pydev.navigator.PythonBaseModelProvider.resourceChanged(PythonBaseModelProvider.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$2.run(NotificationManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:176)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.wizards.files.PythonModuleWizard.doCreateNew(PythonModuleWizard.java:87)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.wizards.files.AbstractPythonWizard.performFinish(AbstractPythonWizard.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.wizards.WizardShortcutAction.run(WizardShortcutAction.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
```

Can anyone say what is wrong in my configuration?.... Thanks in advance..